# Need help in converting alphanumeric column values to NULL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help in replacing alpha numeric values from Col_A to NULL

```
SELECT distinct o_id,
CASE when REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[0-9]+$')=1 then null else Col_A end 
as Col_1
FROM db_name.schema_name.table_name
WHERE date_ordered  = '2022-02-03'
```

When I run the below query, I'm getting one NULL value and one NOT NULL value for O_ID

```
select distinct o_id,Col_A from db_name.schema_name.table_005
WHERE o_id='3351456'
AND date_ordered= '2022-02-03'
```

| O_ID | COL_A |
| --- | --- |
| 93261 | NULL |
| 93261 | ABCDE12345 |

If we add Col_A IS NOT NULL in the WHERE clause, we will not get the NULL value in the result.

Is there any other way to implement this?  The result should not contain NULL value and it should look like below:

| O_ID | COL_A |
| --- | --- |
| 93261 | ABCDE12345 |

Comment: `WHERE o_id='3351456'` and you are get o_id `93261` it seems you example data is VERY inconsistant.

Comment: Also you question say "help with alpha numberic" and the you have a regexp that only matches numeric expressions, and then you want the NULL that you just produced to not be present. So do you want help match/eliminating alpha numeric expressions, or removing numeric?

Comment: if the answer helped, consider marking your question answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a HAVING clause runs after the aggregation stages (the DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT o_id,
CASE when REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[0-9]+$')=1 then null else Col_A END as Col_1
FROM table_005
WHERE date_ordered  = '2022-02-03'
HAVING Col_1 IS NOT NULL;
```

give you your expected results.

| O_ID | COL_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 93261 | ABCDE12345 |

for the following data:

```
create table table_005 AS
     SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (93261, NULL, '2022-02-03'),
        (93261, 'ABCDE12345', '2022-02-03')
        v(O_ID, COL_A, date_ordered);
```

Also

```
CASE when REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[0-9]+$')=1 then null else Col_A END as Col_1
```

can be made smaller by using an IFF

```
IFF( REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[0-9]+$')=1,  null, Col_A) as Col_1b
```

But it actually makes more sense to move this all to the WHERE section with a [REGEXP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html) clause

```
SELECT o_id
    ,Col_A
FROM table_005
WHERE date_ordered  = '2022-02-03' 
  AND col_a not regexp '^[0-9]+$';
```

which gives:

| O_ID | COL_A |
| --- | --- |
| 93261 | ABCDE12345 |

### Alpha Numermic Part

If you are wanting to match alpha numeric's like the title says, you will need to add `a-z` to your match pattern. then you will need to use a case insensitive match (witch will not work on the WHERE REGEXP version) or explicitly match, which could be used:

```
SELECT o_id
    ,Col_A
    ,REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[0-9]+$') as match_just_numbers
    ,REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[a-z0-9]+$',1,'i') as match_alhpa_numeric_case_insensitive
    ,REGEXP_COUNT(Col_A,'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$') as match_alhpa_numeric_explicit
FROM VALUES        
    (1, NULL),
    (2, 'ABCDE12345'),
    (3, '12345'),
    (4, 'ABCDE'),
    (5, 'ABC!DE'),
    (6, '$123.00')
    v(o_id, col_a)
ORDER BY 1
;
```

but the above gives:

| O_ID | COL_A | MATCH_JUST_NUMBERS | MATCH_ALHPA_NUMERIC_CASE_INSENSITIVE | MATCH_ALHPA_NUMERIC_EXPLICIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | ABCDE12345 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 12345 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | ABCDE | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | ABC!DE | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | $123.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

which show you use the exclude not alpha-numeric values you probably should use:

```
SELECT o_id
    ,Col_A
FROM table_005
WHERE date_ordered  = '2022-02-03' 
  AND col_a not regexp '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$';
```

Comment: Thank you so much Simeon. It was of great help :)